# Kivy no longer allowing Resizing of Window?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Yesterday everything was fine but today Kivy wont allow me to resize the window. My app runs but after the window appears i can't seem to make it larger. The window remains the same size it was when i ran app.

```
kivy.config.Config.set('graphics', 'resizable',False)
```

And

```
Window.size = (360,480)
```

Usually when I run my code. Even though kivy opens with set Widow size it is still resizable. However currently it doesn't allow me to do that. I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you might have done a `Config.write()` which saves the current settings to your Kivy `config.ini`, Making them apply to every kivy app thereafter.

Comment: Do you know how I can undo it?

Comment: You can just remove the `config.ini` file. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html#locating-the-configuration-file) for the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John. I had to find Config.ini file and edit it using sublime text. The graphics were set to not resize.

Comment: Yes, you can edit it, or you can just delete it and it will be replaced with the default.